# suggest good example to explain unix input redirection

Tags: unix

Can somebody explain how unix input redirection is used with a good example?

to find a text in a file I can use this approach

grep "text" file.txt

or

grep "text" < file.txt

Both of them give the same output. I'm unable to explain somebody on how unix input redirection can actually be helpful and used?

Comment: `cat test1 test2 > test3`

Comment: Or anything else that doesn't take files as arguments but instead relies on stdin.

Comment: but why would anybody specifically use input redirection when we can do the same without doing the redirection(as shown in the example above).

Comment: So you can chain commands together. Using stdin is common because it allows you to use each tool as part of a larger tool. Being able to redirect stdin just means arbitrary things can be used as standard input.

Answer (score 0):

`grep` supports both stdin (through redirection) and parameter, so here you have no benefit.
With `tr` you can delete '\r' characters from a windows file :

```
cat windowsfile | tr -d '\r' > newunixfile
```

The use of the command `cat` can be avoiding (one less program):

```
tr -d '\r' < windowsfile > newunixfile
```